# Display keyboard when using QFileDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt on a raspberry Pi. I have a QLineEdit that allows me to show a virtual keyboard when clicking on the editline. KeyboardWindow() is my virtual keyboard.

```
class ClickableLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(ClickableLineEdit, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        self.clicked.emit()

    def showKeyboard(self):
        keyboard = KeyboardWindow(self)
        keyboard.show()
```

How I use it :

```
    ck_line = ClickableLineEdit()
    self.ck_line.clicked.connect(ck_line.showKeyboard)
```

I would like to do the same thing in a QFileDialog : for example to save a file : user can browse and search the good repository, ant then he click on the editline to edit file name (via virtual keyboard).

Someone know if there is such signals or how to implement this ?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: there is a c++ implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020752/qfiledialog-with-virtual-keyboard, however I cannot find the qlineedit child of the qfiledialog widget in python, so I cannot give you a "translation". Maybe you can make something out of that?